# Can two containers swap serving the same IP:PORT back and forth in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

### The context

I am trying to run a Minecraft server on TCP/25565, which requires a constantly running server that has access to a large amount of memory and CPU. This would be expensive to run constantly. However, without running it constantly, there's no way for a client to easily connect and turn it on. In order to provide the illusion of an always running service I've come up with a two server solution, one full server and one standby.

### The solution so far

I have two Docker containers which run servers on TCP/25565.

The **full server** runs Minecraft along with a background process that shuts itself down if it ever detects that there are no clients logged in. This code is working just fine.

The **standby server** runs a fake Minecraft server which adheres to the protocol and responds to any login with a message that says "The real server is not yet running. Please wait." and then immediately starts the full server. This code also works.

### The problem

The issue I have is how to make the standby server and the full server share an IP address so that port 25565 is routed to the standby server by default but to the full server whenever it's running. Currently, the standby server always runs in the cheapest way it can with the lowest amount of resources. It starts the full server, but, the full server cannot be connected to in anyway. It's IP address is unknown to the user. I can't seem to find any way in ECS to hot swap the two containers easily. Does anyone know how to do this?

### Possible solutions

I believe this is possible with an Application Load Balancer, however, this would cost $16 a month to run constantly which is not exactly saving money. I'm hoping to run this for less than $5 per month assuming there's no activity on the full server. When there is activity on the full server, it will be paid for by the minute that it's running.

I have looked into a way for an AWS Lambda or something to respond to arbitrary port traffic or spin up an ECS container as a response to port traffic, obviating the need for the always on standby server but I cannot seem to find a solution that does this.

I could completely skip the process and provide a webpage that users go to if the server is not on and this webpage will allow anyone to simply turn on the server.

Comment: You could put a Network Load Balancer in front of the containers and register/deregister them as necessary. You can provide the IP of the load balancer to the clients. Although, load balancers cost money, you would want to check out the prices first.

Comment: Hypothetically, what if the first container proxied traffic to the second container? Disadvantage is that you would lose the ability to IP ban particular players.

Comment: Ha, funny enough I did try this and I just added some context as you were writing this comment. They are about $16 a month. I'm hoping costs for the always on aspect of this are much cheaper. < $5. Hopefully around $1-$3 for no activity.

Comment: I wouldn't mind that proxying the traffic through but I would worry about the latency as well as the smaller server's ability to handle all the traffic if it has minimal resources. That might not be an issue though. It's not like the heavy lifting of the server is in the network traffic. Also writing that port forwarding code would be some effort but nothing I can't do.

Comment: You can run your own reverse proxy, i.e. HAProxy or Nginx to reverse proxy to the right container based. So your idea with the load balancer is the right one. If you want it cheap, roll your own in a container.